# UploadFileAsync get thread and cancel the upload

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, wcf

In my MVC application, when users upload a file, on the controller I call my WCF service which will process with that file (not transfer the file between controler and WCF, the WCF service get the file's content from the File system). Then I use the `System.Net.WebClient` and method `UploadFileAsync()` to send that file to different service (which is hosted by other company and I don't have access to their source).
After that user can click the "Cancel" button which should stop the Upload process.

My question is - is there a way (in MVC Controller or in my WCF service) to find the thread, started with `UploadFileAsync()` - method called before with upload process?

Thank you!

Comment: Won't it be possible to execute UploadFileAsync() as a separate task (or thread), and cancel that task if the user clicks on Cancel?

Comment: @ParagPatil, thank you for your response!
But how to get the thread/task from which executed the UploadFileAsync()? Maybe I need to store somewhere the thread's info, like ID?